# Purpose of two different functions in 'dst_entry' ('input' and 'output') in version 5 of the linux kernel

Tags: networking, routes, linux-kernel

If I understand correctly, in the previous versions of the linux kernel (e.g. version 2) there are two different function pointers in `dst_entry` (namely `input` and `output`) in order to allow for the following scenario (there probably were some other scenarios which required this): during the "egress" of an IP packet that is determined to be destined to the current host, `output` is set to `ip_output` and `input` is set to `ip_local_deliver`. The reason `input` is set in this scenario is because we know the packet will be "delivered back to us", and on the "ingress" path we will now have the `rtable` entry already cached and we can directly call the `input` function pointer. Did I understand this correctly?

However, from what I could see, in the current version of the linux kernel (5) there are different cache entries for the "egress" and the "ingress" path (i.e. the cache entry that is set during the "egress" path will only be retrieved during a future "egress" path, and the same for the "ingress" path). These entries are `nhc_pcpu_rth_output` (for "egress") and `nhc_rth_input` (for "ingress") inside `fib_nh_common`.

Most probably there is a scenario that I am missing which involves setting the `output` function during "ingress" and then using it in the future during the "egress" path or vice-versa.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could point out the reason for having the two different function pointers inside `dst_entry` (`input` and `output`) in the current version of the linux kernel.

Thank you.

Comment: @JustinIurman Thank you for your answer. I read the code more and I thought of two scenarios where setting both `input` and `output` on the same `dst_entry` is required. The first scenario, **packet forwarding**: an IP packet arrives at an interface; routing determines it is not destined for this host, therefore it must be forwarded; `input` is set to `ip_forward` and `output` is set to `ip_output` (`ip_forward` will eventually call `output`). The second scenario, **sending packet to current host**: `output` is set to `ip_output` and `input` is set to `ip_local_deliver`. [continued]

Comment: When the packet "comes back" from the loopback interface it already has the `dst` structure filled (the check happens inside ip_input.c, inside `ip_rcv_finish_core`: `if (!skb_valid_dst(skb)) ... `, so the `input` function can be called without having to go through the whole routing process again. Do I understand this correctly now?

Comment: Your first scenario is correct, not your second. Indeed, there is no difference between the two. Actually, when the packet is for local host, `input` will be set to `ip6_input` (I'll take IPv6 as the example because I'm more familiar with it, but it should be quite similar for IPv4) and `output` won't be used since it's useless in this case. As a summary, when the packet is for the host, `input` will be `ip6_input` (which will then call `ip6_protocol_deliver_rcu`). If the packet is not for the host, `input` will be `ip6_forward` and `output` will be `ip6_output`.

Comment: @JustinIurman Thank you again for your response! I am sorry, I should have been more specific. For my second scenario, **sending packet to current host**, I was referirng to the situation in which one host sends a packet to itself (e.g. it sends a packet to 127.0.0.1, in case that is the address of the loopback interface). Considering this clarification, is the flow that I described correct?

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Well, it probably does not happen the way you described, though I'm not sure where in the code it is handled. The thing is, the packet won't leave and re-enter your node since the destination address is the loopback, it will be delivered directly (again, there is something on the `output` side to resolve that, but `input` does not come into play here). In fact, `input` never comes into play when it is about packets sent from your node. The closest thing to your reasoning I could think of is that the packet would be re-injected in the network stack and then `input` would be set.

Comment: @JustinIurman I think that in this scenario the packet arrives at the "driver" of the loopback interface, where it is put directly in the "receive queue". Then, it passes through the "ingress" path, but the `skbuff` structure has the `dst` field already set, which means that the packet does not need to go through the "routing" step, and the `input` function (set during the "egress" path) is called (or why else would that check (that I previously mentioned) in `ip_rcv_finish_core` to see if the `dst` field of the `skbuff` structure is valid be done?).